# Mask Image URL and make it look like its on your web server

Tags: php, mysql

How would i go about making a page called banner.php on my site and have that page look up a banner id in my db (already know how to look it up and fetch the url), but how would i go about making it seem like its the actual image destination if i wanted to use myurl.com/banner.php?bid=3 in a  tag on someone else's website.

Regards,
Jarrod

Anyone who can help on how to do this its appreciated!

Comment: use web server URL rewrite trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your banner.php you have to actually load the image from its real server and output it again in your banner.php. Be sure to send the correct Content-Type header, so the browsers take your PHP-file as an image.

The quickest code for your banner.php I can imagine for a jpeg-image may look like this:

```
<?php
$imageContents = file_get_contents('http://example.com/real-banner.jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $imageContents;
```

When a user then calls http://your-domain.com/banner.php it is shown as an image in the browser, not knowing where its original source was.

**Hints:**

- Change the header Content-Type to `image/png` or `image/gif` depending on the image type.
- If you are using `file_get_contents()`, be sure that your server support [fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen), otherwise using URLs in `file_get_contents()` won't work. See the [Notes-Section of file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-get-contents-notes)
- Another method for getting content from another server would be the [PHP curl library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

**Edit:**
If you want to output the same header the original image has, you can iterate through the variable `$http_response_header` which gets autofilled with the headers after a `file_get_contents` call. Search for the `Content-Type` header and output it the same.

```
<?php
$imageContents = file_get_contents('http://example.com/real-banner.jpg');
// get the content type header out of the file_get_contents request
foreach ($http_response_header as $header) {
    if (strtolower(substr($header, 0, 13)) == 'content-type:') {
        $origContentTypeHeader = $header;
        break;
    }
}
header($origContentTypeHeader);
echo $imageContents;
```

Comment: How would i go about not having to use the thing after /image

Comment: I won't know what kind of image it is all the time

Comment: i get that instead of the image

Comment: You're youputting a .png but sending a image/webp image header. Look at the Edit in my above answer on how to retrieve the original Content-Type header.